# xmlstarlet replaces nodes that do not match the xpath

Tags: xml, pom.xml, xmlstarlet

Trying to use xmlstarlet to set the version on a pom.xml
The problem is that it sets the values of ALL "value" nodes in the pom.xml and not just the one that matches the XPATH
Here is what I am using:

```
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -N x=http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 -u '//x:project//x:version' -v $NEWVERSION pom.xml
```

So it works but with the unwanted side-effect of setting the value in other xpaths like /project/parent/version and /project/dependencies/dependency/version
Why is it doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it doing that?

Because you asked for it. `//` is
[shorthand](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#path-abbrev)
for `/descendant-or-self::node()/` so the XPath expression
`//x:project//x:verston`
targets all `version` elements which are descendants of any `project` element in the namespace bound to prefix `x`.

To change only the `version` which is the child of the root element
`project`, for example:

```sh
xmlstarlet edit --inplace -u '/_:project/_:version' -v $NEWVERSION pom.xml
```

where the default namespace is bound to the `_` (underscore) prefix
since it is declared in the root element (user's guide
[ch. 5](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html#idm47989546151216)).